# How to filter duplicate rows based on a condition in tsql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, filter, duplicates

I have an employee table with duplicate records consisting of contract to hire or rebadge details.

| FullName | Status | Current Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Inactive | Finance Analyst |
| John Doe | Active | Finance Manager |
| Mike Wood | Active | Project Manager |
| Mike Wood | Inactive | Consultant |
| Sam Hyke | Inactive | Director |
| Ahmed Saeed | Active | Supply Chain Manager |

I would like to select all records irrespective of status and only in case of duplicates, it should filter and pick the rows with status as 'Active'.

Expected Outcome

| FullName | Status | Current Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Active | Finance Manager |
| Mike Wood | Active | Project Manager |
| Sam Hyke | Inactive | Director |
| Ahmed Saeed | Active | Supply Chain Manager |

Comment: What is expected outcome out of your example data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 1 with ties FullName,Status,[Current Position]
from yourtable
order by row_number() over(partition by FullName order by case Status when 'Active' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: This will select inactive preferably.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You can select `DISTINCT` `FullName`, ordering the table by `FullName`, `Status`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FullName,
       Status,       
       [Current Position]
FROM employees
ORDER BY FullName, Status;
```

After reordering, `'Active'` will always be in first position. *(if exists)*

Comment: This would still give me the duplicates with non-active status.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 1 with ties full_name "Full Name",Status,current_position "Current Position"
from employee
order by row_number() over(partition by full_name order by case Status when 'Active' then 0 else 1 end)
```

Comment: again, its the same query given by George in this thread.

Comment: Some modified. Please run this, you will get expected output. https://imgur.com/a/0UwG2X0

Comment: ok great. Thanks, George and Syed. There was a small mistake in my query. Now there is another issue for names with further initials like John A. Doe. Can we apply the above on two columns simultaneously like First Name and Last Name?